# Display different content on each click using JS

Tags: javascript, function, click, addeventlistener

I've got an example code of what I'm trying to do - where when you click on one of the size's i.e the li then it would display the size & price of that item in a new div called price.

What currently happens is no matter which li i choose the first size & price is displayed and it keeps added a new div. Where what i want is for whatever li that is clicked to be displayed and for the inner content of the div to be replaced each time. Any help on where i'm going wrong would be appreciated.

```js
var sizeSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.container li');
sizeSelector.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    runFunction();
  });
});

function runFunction() {
  var newPrice = document.querySelector('.container li').innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('.container').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div class='price'>" + newPrice + "</div>");
  console.log(newPrice);
}
```

```html
<ul class='container'>
  <li>Size Small $20</li>
  <li>Size Medium $30</li>
  <li> Size large $40</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you used just needed a small adjustment to the `runFunction`, and for the `div` containing the price `class` to be included in the original HTML template. By doing that, we can target that div and update its content alone.

```js
var sizeSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.container li');
sizeSelector.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    runFunction(evt);
  });
});

function runFunction(evt) {
  const newPrice = document.querySelector('.container li').innerHTML;
  const priceDiv = document.querySelector('.price');
  priceDiv.innerHTML = evt.target.innerHTML;
  console.log(priceDiv.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul class='container'>
  <li>Size Small $20</li>
  <li>Size Medium $30</li>
  <li>Size large $40</li>
</ul>
<div class='price'></div>
```

Comment: This is great thank you. I was hoping i could've used this solution to get what i need but it doesn't seem to work. In my example ,the li only contains the size. And the price of the items gets outputted into a separate div when clicked. What i want to do is knowing how to target the price each time it's changed and to console log this out as each time i do this i only get the first price.

Comment: @leek1234 You'll need to add functionality to the `runFunction` such that it can pull the price information to include that in the `div` with the price `class`. It doesn't seem clear from what you've shared where that price information lives though.

Comment: @leek1234 Okay, I see what you mean. Your feedback is because of the console statement. I just  made that adjustment to show the new price in logging.

Comment: On my original code It's more that the lis are: <li>size small</li><li>Size medium</li> then when this is clicked then it would output the price of the size - this is how the site currently works. But what i'm trying to do is to target the price change each time it's clicked so i can make other calculations with this. But i'm unable to do this as each time i try to get the new price it only prints the first price it sees which is $20. Was hoping the example code i supplied i could then work this into what i need

Comment: @leek1234 My point is that if we make that adjustment to your example, then no prices appear in the `ul` - only sizes. But you are stating that you want price to appear in the div with price class and in logging. So I'm assuming that prices appear somewhere but are not provided in the example. Without knowing where they are, you will need to find them and add that into the updated content. Depending on where they are stored, you may be able to just use `querySelector` and find the HTML where it's stored.

Comment: Yes yes i know my example above doesn't show the prices elsewhere, like i said i was trying to use this as a quick example to try and use the solution to get what i want but it doesn’t quite work how i would like. Thanks for your help though it is much appreciated.